# How to get better reports from Keras?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I love Keras for its versatility, but I would like to have better reporting when it is fitting. I now write directly in tensorflow but I'd prefer to do it in Keras. Is there some way to write something like:

```
while more work to do:
    keras_model.fit 1 epoch (X, y, and other parameters)
    report progress of training set, test set, etc
```

of course, when the model resumes the next fit resumes from its preserved state. I could not find something like that except for saving and reloading but that seems some kind of overkill. I tried something like

```
for i in range (10):
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, verbose=0, epochs=1, batch_size=128)
    train_score, Pc = get_results(classifier, X_train, y_train)
    test_score, Pc_test = get_results(classifier, X_test, y_test)
    print (i, train_score, test_score)
```

and it seems to actually work. Is this a way of doing it or am I making some horrible mistake?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by "states"? Is it a model using recurrent networks with `stateful=True`?

Comment: Arn't you trying to do what verbose already does?

Comment: @djk47463, exactly, but I am dissatisfied about its reporting. I want the accuracy (sometimes ROC) of train and test scores together with the cost.

Comment: @Daniel Moller, after fitting some epochs the model has estimated parameters, What I would like to know is when I start to fit again as I do in the loop of the example above, does it resume fitting where it remained or does it start all over again? It's just a simple network with two dense layers.

Comment: Then your model has only "weights", not "states" ("states" are related to recurrent networks, and are important for continuing sequence input data). The weights will be preserved, you can stop and start training as many times as you want.

Comment: Once the `classifier.compile` statement is executed, a tensor flow environment is created, which is why you can call `model.predict()`, and it predicts on the network, unless you delete `classifier` the model will retain its weights, until python stop executing. So yes, the for loop works, and does not start a zero for each iteration

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Moller and djk47463 for your explanations! That is what I wanted to know.

Comment: Just an additional info: the model will have its weights (and preserve it) even if you don't call `classifier.compile`. Compilation in keras is necessary for defining a loss function and an optimizer for training, but you can use `classifier.predict()` without compiling the model.